# How to determine the order of separate integers in C?

Tags: c, integer

I'm trying to program an algorithm that uses the order of five separate integers to determine what to do. However I need to know in which order the integers come. I'm new on this site, so I'm sorry if this question is to vague or the info given is not enough. Here is the code:

```
{
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main ()
  {
    int a=1;
    int b=0;
    int c=0;
    int d=1;
    int e=1;

    /* Program that determines the order. */

   return 0
   }
```

As you can see int a is created before int b. b before c ect. I need a program that can "call" (so to speak) the integer that came 1st, 2ed, ect. in sequence. How do I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason those are *not* in an `int ar[5];` ?

Comment: That is a good point, I considered using arrays in the program that I'm working on. I thought that it wouldn't work. Now that I see that arrays will work.

Comment: "int a is created before int b" is not so.  There is no sequencing required here.  Compiler is free to create the 5 in any order and even do so simultaneously.  Further, these 5 need not even have address.

Answer (score 1):

You must check adresses of int by using :

```
&a; &b...
```

then the order of int should appear by ascending order.

Care about adress of local var without pointers.
Adresses are only available on local function, if you pass them as arguments in other function, local variable will be duplicate so the adress will change !

Get adresses of your int (code):

```
int addr[5]; 
addr[0] = &a; // if &a == 0 {
addr[1] = &b; // &b = sizeof(int) * 1
addr[2] = &c; // &c = sizeof(int) * 2
addr[3] = &d; // &d = sizeof(int) * 3
addr[4] = &e; // &e = sizeof(int) * 4 }
```

Comment: Just see the answer of @WhozCraig and you should definitivly use int [5].

Comment: How would I print off these integers though?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
printf("%x = %d\n", addr[0]);

Is showing hexa value of adress of int a and decimal value

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I was online when you replied, and I immediately tried your solution. It seems to work, but it said that a was equal to zero. I have a set to equal one. Is there something I have done wrong? Maybe there is a symbol that you forgot to add?

Comment: all of my code is just what I posted in my question plus your answer plus your printf statement in that order.

Comment: I hope it is obvious that `int addr[5]` is, in fact, an `int` array, and is being used as if it were an `int *` array. It would seem someone forgot an asterisk, as this should be spewing compiler warnings, if not errors, with authority.

Comment: This code is assigning the address of a pointer to an `int`.   An `int` may be insufficient to hold to the entire address.  Why not use `int *addr[5]; `?  (add *)

Comment: Would you kindly explain further? I have dealt with arrays vary little, and don't know what you mean.